# Opposites, when dealing with adjectives and objects together

Tags: adjectives, antonyms

If we have the sentence,
"Bob had blinding love for Susan."
would the opposite be:
"Bob had blinding hatred for Susan"
or:
"Bob had clear hatred for Susan"?

Answer (score 5):

In either case, I think the opposition comes from the emotion: love vs. hate.  The adjective serves to denote the depth of the emotion, and to me it makes sense that the depth be similar in both cases.  So I'd vote for "blinding love" and "blinding hatred".  On a related note, "blinding" in both cases refers to the emotion's effect on Bob; "clear" implies to me that Bob's emotion is obvious to outside observers.

Comment: +1 for addressing the difference between the "blind" and "clear" distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Blinding.

Love blinds.  Hate also blinds.  There isn't anything wrong with it grammatically or meaning-wise to warrant changing it.

"Clear" would imply a lesser hatred than "blinding" and would not be a true opposite.